# Itemize skills section in Awesome-CV

Tags: lists, cv, resume, bullets, awesome-cv

I'd like to make a bulleted list inside the skills section in my CV. I am using the Awesome-CV template at https://github.com/posquit0/Awesome-CV. Currently, my skills.tex file looks like this:

```
\begin{cvskills}

\cvskill
{Technical skills} % Category
{MS Office, Python, R, SQL, MATLAB, Mathematica, LaTeX, Git, PyQt} % Skills

\end{cvskills}
```

But, I'd like to add some code (itemize etc.) to make it look like this:

[image]

So basically adding one layer to my current code by making a bulleted list under \cvskill "Technical skills". This requires some new code that I am now asking for.

I already tried itemize and some other approaches but they all looked terrible or did not compile.

Hopefully, someone in the forum would be willing to help by providing a suggestion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is another variant that keeps the entry in the format of other entries under `cvskils`.

[image: b]

```
\begin{cvskills}    
        
        \cvskill
        {Technical skills}
        {\begin{minipage}[t]{0.7\textwidth}
            MS Office, Python, R, SQL, MATLAB, Mathematica, LaTeX, Git, PyQt
                \begin{itemize}
                    \item Conducted data cleaning an manipulation and multiple regresion in my BSc thesis using R.
                    \item Conducted a study pn Delta hedging an Delta-Vega hedging stock index option with R.
                \end{itemize}
        \end{minipage}
        }

 %Other entries ....
    
\end{cvskills}
```

To suppress the left indent of items, add to the document preamble

```
\usepackage{enumitem}
\setlist[itemize]{leftmargin=*}
```

[image: c]

Comment: Thanks! This was exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using the `cvskills` environment, you could use the `cventries` environment and then use `cvitems` instead of `itemize` to create your list, keeping the arguments for location and date empty like so:

```
\begin{cventries}
  \cventry
    {MS Office, Python, R, SQL, MATLAB, Mathematica, LaTeX, Git, PyQt} % Skills
    {Technical skills} % Category
    {} % Location
    {} % Date
    {
      \begin{cvitems}
            \item {Conducted data cleaning and -manipulation and multiple regression in my BSc thesis using R} 
            \item {Conducted a study on Delta hedging and Delta-Vega hedging stock index options using R} 
      \end{cvitems}
    }
\end{cventries}
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. This approach looks quite good but I prefer that the actual skills pop up a bit more. Hence, I think Simon Dispa's suggestion suits me better.